# How do you pass a value to the variable in a xhr.setRequestHeader?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to pass a value to the variable in xhr.setRequestHeader(Authentication, "Bearer" + variable); using xmlhttprequest.  How do you pass a value to the variable in a xhr.setRequestHeader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an error in your code, the "Authentication" part should be a string, and for the Bearer type it has to be "Authorization":

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + variable);
```

Comment: I need coffee!!